# How to override the built-in JSON formatter / JSON converter in NLog ≥ v5.0?

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

In our project, we have some class properties that we want to censor when being logged. Each property that is to be censored is attributed with a custom-defined attribute; let's call it `CensorMeAttribute`.

Hence, any property we want to censor may be implemented as:

```
[CensorMe]
public string Secret { get; set; }
```

---

We currently override NLog's built-in JSON formatter/converter in order to censor the value of the `CensorMe`-attributed properties by following the guidelines provided by NLog's wiki article on [How to use structured logging](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#how-to-override-json-formatter):

1. We have implemented a custom `NLog.IJsonConverter` with the following signature:

```
public class CensorJsonConverter : NLog.IJsonConverter
```

and the appropriate logic for our use-case.

2. In our project's `Program.cs`, we currently override the JSON converter and enable NLog as logging provider in this static method:

```
private static void AddNLog(HostBuilderContext context, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
{
    NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.JsonConverter = new CensorJsonConverter();

    var config = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("NLog"));

    loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config);
}
```

Here, the call to `loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config)` is a call to [`ILoggingBuilder.AddNLog(LoggingConfiguration)`](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Extensions_Logging_ConfigureExtensions_AddNLog_6.htm).

With this implementation, `Secret` is logged as `\"Secret\":\"***\"` rather than `\"Secret\":\"actual secret value\"`. **This is the desired logging output, which we want to keep.**

---

Upon upgrading the NLog package version to ≥ v5.0, [`NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.JsonConverter`](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/P_NLog_Config_ConfigurationItemFactory_JsonConverter.htm) became obsolete. The workaround message says:

> Instead use LogFactory.ServiceRepository.ResolveInstance(typeof(IJsonConverter)).

I cannot find any `ResolveInstance()` method on the `LogFactory.ServiceRepository` property. There is the `RegisterService()` method, which *registers instance of singleton object for use in NLog* ([`ServiceRepository` docs](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/T_NLog_Config_ServiceRepository.htm)). What I hence have tried is to replace the line

```
NLog.[...].JsonConverter = new CensorJsonConverter();
```

with a call to

```
config.LogFactory.ServiceRepository.RegisterService([...]);
```

as follows:

```
private static void AddNLog(HostBuilderContext context, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
{
    var config = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("NLog"));

    config.LogFactory.ServiceRepository.RegisterService(
        typeof(CensorJsonConverter),
        new CensorJsonConverter());

    loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config);
}
```

With this implementation, `Secret` is logged as `\"Secret\":\"actual secret value\"`. This is **not** the desired logging output.

---

How do I override the built-in JSON converter without setting the now (NLog ≥ v5.0) obsolete `NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.JsonConverter`?

Or is there perhaps another way to achieve a similar handling of the `CensorMe`-attributed properties, with or without the use of NLog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```cs
private static void AddNLog(HostBuilderContext context, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
{
    LogManager.Setup()
      .SetupExtensions(e => e.RegisterNLogWeb().RegisterConfigSettings(context.Configuration))
      .SetupSerialization(s => s.RegisterJsonConverter(new CensorJsonConverter())
      .LoadConfigurationFromSection(context.Configuration);
    loggingBuilder.AddNLogWeb();
}
```

Notice that if you wrap your secrets in a custom type that inherits from `IFormattable`, then NLog will by default ignore properties and just do `ToString()` (No need for custom JsonConverter)

```
public struct SecretValue : IFormattable
{
    public string Value;

    string IFormattable.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider) => ToString();
    public override string ToString() => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) ? "" : "*****";
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#customize-object-reflection

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first suggested approach seems to work very well! I have made two changes: Omitting the `.RegisterNLogWeb()` call, and calling `loggingBuilder.AddNLog();` rather than `loggingBuilder.AddNLogWeb();` (simply because we currently don't have the `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` package installed). In your opinion, should we install that package and use the NLogWeb-approach regardless?

Comment: As a side comment: The approach with creating a `struct` that inherits from `IFormattable` is less relevant in our use case, seeing as the classes that contain the `[CensorMe]`-decorated properties are classes whose instances are being populated directly from the config files. Hence, keeping those properties as simple `string` properties has its benefits for us. But it's a good option to know about for later possible scenarios.

Comment: @AstridE. If you are not using any features from `NLog.Web.AspNetCore`, then you should not install it. And you should just remove `RegisterNLogWeb` and change to `AddNLog()`.